# Magento 2.2 Add Unit Price in Order Email Template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

Add Unit Price (Base Price) in Order email Confirmation in magento 2.2.3

https://prnt.sc/u0po5q

We have Porto theme

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Sales/templates/email >>    
  items/>>         
     oreder/default.phtml         
     price/row.phtml      
items.phtml
```

Comment: Both solutions you are trying is for magento 1